# What is 'cones of line'?

Tags: word-meaning

> A sign. IGS STORE. The store in a house. Dark room. Behind the counter
>   they could see a kitchen, teakettle spitting on the stove. Bunny heard
>   television laughter. Waiting for someone to appear, Quoyle examined
>   bear-paw snowshoes. Walked around, looking at the homemade shelves,
>   open boxes of skinning knives, needles for mending net, **cones of line**,
>   rubber gloves, potted meats, a pile of adventure videos. Bunny peered
>   through the freezer door at papillose frost crowding the ice cream
>   tubs.

*The Shipping News by Annie Proulx*

I googled and looked up the dictionary but can't figure out what they are.

Comment: Probably means a tapered spool of line (string): http://www.sswdealersupply.com/cone-of-balloon-string-00202.aspx?source=0&sku=00202&gclid=CKqbp76_9soCFQMQaQodf38H6A

Comment: @ Jim... Do you mind posting an answer for this? I would like to wrap up my question with  a green ' V ' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Line" here probably means a fishing line, which is a string that is typically wrapped around a cylinder or a cone to form a spool.